# Can't install Django, runserver error

Tags: python, django

So I have been trying to set up Django, the way it's showed on youtube by thenewboston (a.k.a. Bucky Roberts). This is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHjXtRrhqxc&index=2&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK
 But when I run the server I get errors like

```
PS C:\Users\Dante\Desktop> django-admin startproject MyProject1
PS C:\Users\Dante\Desktop> cd .\MyProject1
PS C:\Users\Dante\Desktop\MyProject1> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\Dante\Desktop\MyProject1


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2017-06-29     12:17                .idea
d-----       2017-06-29     12:13                MyProject1
-a----       2017-06-29     12:13            830 manage.py


PS C:\Users\Dante\Desktop\MyProject1> python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?
Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
PS C:\Users\Dante\Desktop\MyProject1> python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?
Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

in the code. How do I fix that ?

Comment: Have you installed Django in your system? If not please do so first. Assuming you have pip(a Python package manager) installed, then you can install Django using this command `pip install Dango`. But first you can check if Django is installed by either `pip show` Django or `pip list`.

Comment: Paste code as snippet not screenshot enxt time. How have you created the project? Are you using virtual environment?

Comment: Please replace your image by *text*. Images can't be searched, can't be seen by everyone... See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

create the virtualenv (virtualenv venv). Activate that virtualenv( source venv/bin/activate). Then install django.